# How to use hook_menu to add an item to the secondary links?

Tags: routes, hooks

Adding an item to the primary links is easy:

```
function hook_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['bla'] = array(
        'title' => 'bla',
        'page callback' => 'mymod_blah',
        'expanded' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

This adds it to the primary links. How do I add it to the secondary links?

Comment: Take a look at the `menu_name` key of [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

Comment: I read that page 10 times and I couldnt see that. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `menu_name` to specify the menu of the items you are adding:

See the [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) docs for more info.

For example, to add the item to the main menu:

```
function hook_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['bla'] = array(
        'title' => 'bla',
        'page callback' => 'mymod_blah',
        'expanded' => TRUE,
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    );
    return $items;
}
```